# Переменная объекта в делфи - это указатель?

Tags: delphi, указатели, объекты

Вот в чем вопрос. Например у меня есть класс MyClass. Я создаю переменную типа MyClass с именем var1 и инициализирую ее var1:= MyClass.Create. Вопрос, предположим что я передаю в функцию эту переменную, функция объявлена так:

```
function MyFunc1(input: MyClass): integer;
```

Если я сделаю:

```
MyFunc1(var1);
```

В функцию передастся копия моей переменной, или указатель(ссылка) на нее? И аналогично с result. Если у меня есть функция:

function MyFunc2: MyClass;

И в ее теле я верну некоторую переменную типа MyClass, то есть сделаю Result:= MyClass, то вернется копия или указатель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указатель. И функция будет работать с объектом созданным за ее пределами. Когда функция передает объект в `Result` то это, также, указатель.

Comment: Спасибо.
А есть встроенные средства для передачи копии объекта, или нужно копирующий конструктор делать?

Comment: Если объект наследуется от `TPersistent` то копировать свойства можно методом `Assign()`.

Comment: @Jakeroid
 Assign() и   AssignTo() это условное правило где именно должно проиcходить копирование объекта но если в вашем классе она не переопределена то ниче не скопируется. Вы сами должны указать какие поля объекта должны копироваться и написать свой код. или через Rtti чето намудрить для общего копирования объектов.

Comment: если вы хотите по простому работать с копиями можете record использовать при присвоении он копируется если в нем примитивные типы если в нем объекты то ссылки на объекты скопируются. record можно передать ввиде ссылки на него Trec тип PRec ссылка на тип record и классы c буквы T должны начинаться что бы другие вас легче понимали да и вы сами свой код могли читать спустя время.

Comment: @vegat4 ого, спасибо за ответ, правда я уже делфи не использовал наверно почти 10 лет :D